# Component "font-awesome-icon" has already been registered in target app (NuxtJS 3)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome

I'm using NuxtJS 3 with FontAwesome. I've managed to get it working, but I receive a warning the console of my IDE which says:

```
[Vue warn]: Component "font-awesome-icon" has already been registered in target app.
```

Where does it come from? Is this a problem? And how to fix this?

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^3.0.0-0",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6",
    "sass": "^1.54.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
    "firebase": "^9.9.1"
  }
}
```

My `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    plugins: [
        '~/plugins/fontawesome.ts',
        '~/plugins/firebase.client.ts'
    ],
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/google-fonts'
    ],
    googleFonts: {
        display: 'swap',
        prefetch: true,
        preconnect: true,
        preload: true,
        families: {
            Nunito: true,
        }
    },
    css: [
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css',
    ],
    runtimeConfig: {
        FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    },
})
```

And the fontawesome plugin in `~/plugins/fontawesome.ts`:

```js
import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "nuxt/app";

config.autoAddCss = false

library.add(fas)
library.add(fab)
library.add(far)

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    // This line creates problems with TypeScript whereas it is not raising any runtime error
    // @ts-ignore
    nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon, {});
});
```

Several problems:

- TypeScript doesn't like calling `nuxtApp.vueApp.component()` like this because apparently there is no such function declared for 3 arguments given by the [FontAwesome documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue/use-with#nuxt)
- The warning is annoying and I don't find anything that could help me.

My icons do show up (so it looks like this is working despite the warning).

Did I do something wrong?